# Unable to connect to remote redis host [nodeJS]

Tags: node.js, express, redis, node-redis

```js
const redis = require('redis');
require('dotenv').config();
console.log(process.env.redisHost, ':', process.env.redisPort);
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
    host: process.env.redisHost,
    port: process.env.redisPort,
    password: process.env.redisKey
});
redisClient.connect();
redisClient.on('error', err => console.log('Redis error: ', err.message));
redisClient.on('connect', () => console.log('Connected to redis server'));
module.exports = redisClient;
```

I tried this sample from redis docs but still I'm getting an error stating:
`Redis error:  connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379`

I logged the environment host and port variables to the console and I got the remote host ipv4 address, but still the client is trying to connect to localhost instead of remote host (I purposely uninstalled redis from my local device to check if the client is working as it is supposed to). I also confirmed that the remote redis host is working perfectly.

I also tried different methods like :
https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-redis-on-appengine

```
redis.createClient(port, host, {auth_pass: password});
```

But still, I got the same error.

I am able to connect to the redis host via commandline:

```
redis-cli.exe -h XX.XX.XX.XXX -a Password
XX.XX.XX.XXX:6379> set name dhruv
OK
XX.XX.XX.XXX:6379> get name
"dhruv"
XX.XX.XX.XXX:6379> exit
```

I'm trying to use redis on nodejs for the first time, so don't have a proper idea but I think I am doing everything right.
Any solution/workaround will be helpful :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It worked with this code:

```js
const url = `redis://${process.env.redisHost}:${process.env.redisPort}`;
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
    url,
    password: process.env.redisKey
});
redisClient.connect();
```

Answer (score 1):

The configuration object changed in redis v4, you can view the new options [here](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/client-configuration.md). Below is how I've configured it in my project.

```
const redisClient = redis.createClient({ socket: { port: process.env.redisPort, host: process.env.redisHost }  })
redisClient.connect()
```

Answer (score 0):

can you check if in the destination the port is reachable. it maybe the firewall block your access

Comment: yes it is, I am even able to use it remotely from my device.
But the problem is that the redis client is not even trying to connect to the remote host. It is trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 instead of remote ip address

Comment: usualy redis get ip from config file , please change the redis configuration from config file installdir/redis/etc/redis. conf

Comment: another suggestion try to use docker for redis connection

Comment: What field in particular should I search in the redis conf file? Can you help me with that? like is it `cluster-ip`? Also, for now I don't want to use docker as I am having a problem with my database in docker, so I was looking for a already deployed version of redis

Comment: try this way
https://redis.js.org/
https://github.com/redis/node-redis
in this website you can find how to connect without config file and how you put the information

Comment: Still not able to connect to redis this way :/ . What I don't understand is why is my client trying to connect to localhost instead of the remote host even if I added remotehost ip in the function!!

Comment: can you try it the redis connection on the command line ?

Comment: Yeah, you can check, I edited the question itself

Comment: can you check if the value of the ip address in the nodejs is true ?

Comment: do you mean with regex?
const match = /^(?!0)(?!.*\.$)((1?\d?\d|25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d)(\.|$)){4}$/;
console.log(match.test(process.env.redisHost));
I'm getting true for this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to a remote redis db in an express nodejs app, you need to pass the url like this:

```
const url = `rediss://default:your_password@your_host:your_port`;
const client = redis.createClient({
    url,
});
```

note that your host should start with something like private-db-redis-nyc3... or db-redis..., if you find `redis://` don't include it.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to connect to a redis instance running on localhost with the url `localhost:port` but what made it work for me was using `127.0.0.1:port` instead